# How can I force Firebase to give me a new serverTimeOffset instead of caching it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using Firebase to have a countdown across multiple users.  I use the Firebase .info/serverTimeOffset to calculate what the time should be across clients.  The problem is that the value gets cached, and so far the only way I've been able to get past the caching is to do a full reload of the firebase library, and then create a new Firebase object, and then use that one.  That has been the only way to get an updated offset so far.  Is there a better way?

Comment: FYI - This value is the estimated per-connection time differential between the client and server, so for a given connection, it shouldn't change until a new connection is created. Would `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` solve your use case?

Comment: Unfortunately it wouldn't, because that is simply used to resolve a timestamp value when it hits the Firebase server.  This is for local use, to keep a timer accurate even if for some reason they change their local time clock.

Comment: In that case, you could try resetting the Firebase connection via `Firebase.goOffline()` and Firebase.goOnline()`.

Comment: Thanks @RobDiMarco , that actually works, however it does cause some other minor problems, but it helps a lot :)